# Data Structure and Algorithms

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I got stuck with this data structure and Algorithm problem.

Labels of below array: `[Id, Label, ParentId]`

```
var dataSet = [[5, 'a', 2], [2, 'b', 5], [5, 'c', 20], [20, 'x', null], [5, 'd', 2]];
```

Here we can find Parent which contains null which means [20, 'x', null] array becomes the parent root.

Then, Parent Id should match to its child node `[20, 'x', null]` array ID matching to `[5, 'c', 20]` array parent ID.

**Below format that I'm looking for Parent and Child relation**

```
 - Parent Root: [20,'x']  [20,'x',null] 
 - ChildNode:  ->[5, 'c'] [5,'c',20] 
 - SubChild:   ->->[2,'b'] [2,'b',5] 
 - nextSub:   ->->->[5,'a'] [5,'a',2] 
 - final node: ->->->[5,'d'] [5,'d',2]
```

So which data structure and which algorithm can we develop in javascript?

Comment: *"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"* Please read: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What is the output you expect from this? An array with the correct order in terms of ancestry? A list? A tree?

Comment: Well, the data structure that you are describing is a tree. Are you asking for the most efficient way to take the input in the original format and arrive at the tree? Once you have the tree, you can get the output by iterating over it.

Comment: you have a circular structure ... please add the wanded result as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create recursive function using `reduceRight` because we will use `splice` but then you should also `reverse` it.

```js
const data = [[5, 'a', 2], [2, 'b', 5], [5, 'c', 20], [20, 'x', null], [5, 'd', 2]];

function f(data, pid = null) {
  return data.reverse().reduceRight((r, [id, str, parent], i) => {
    if (pid == parent) {
      const el = [id, str, parent];
      data.splice(i, 1);

      const children = f(data, id);
      if (children.length) el.push(...children);
      r.push(el)
    }
    return r;
  }, []);
}

const result = f(data);
console.log(result);
```